# Need to move the out of stock items to the end of result set in elastic search

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, elasticsearch

I have the following search query

```
{ 
   "index":"index",
   "body":{ 
      "sort":{ 
         "sort_order":[ 
            { 
               "order":"asc",
               "missing":"_last"
            }
         ]
      },
      "query":{ 
         ....
         ....
      }
   }
}
```

This returns a list of products for a search query and sorts the results based on a field named `sort_order`. And if the `sort_order` field is null, it pushes those items to the end of the result set.

**Sample product record**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "product A",
    "variants": [
        {
            "variant_id": 1,
            "stock": 114,
            "published": 1,
        }
    ],
    "sort_order": 1
},
```

Here you can see the `stock` field with a value of 114 which depicts the number of items available (We show it as "out of stock" in the front end if the stock is zero ), also a product can have multiple variants.

**What I am trying to achieve?**

I need to push the items with stock equals to `0` to the end of the result set, just like the `sort` parameter already does with the `sort_order` field. (Sorting based on the `stock` field is not preferred since it will mess up the other relevant items as well.)
How can I achieve this?

One thing that comes to my mind is somehow set the `_score` for items with zero stock to `null` so it goes to the end of result set. But no clue about how to achieve that as well. Any hints to tackle it, this is greatly appreciated.